# Integral Transform (Weierstrass transform of PDF of t-distributions)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let's recall two things.

1.

Weierstrass transform W(ξ) is defined by

$$W(ξ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4π}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(ξ - x)^2}{4}}f(x) \,dx.$$, that is, the convolution of f with the Gaussian function.

2.

The probability density function of Student's t distribution with n degress of freedom is $$f_n(x) = c(1 + \frac{x^2}{n})^\frac{-(n+1)}{2}.$$
where c is a normalization constant $c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}B(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})}$ and B is the beta function.

Considering 1 and 2, we get
$$W(ξ) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{4π}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(ξ - x)^2}{4}}(1 + \frac{x^2}{n})^\frac{-(n+1)}{2}\,dx.$$

Please solve this. I’m very curious of what this will be. But it’s over my capabilities.

Comment: Add more information please: what you tried, where you got stuck, etc. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, but I totally can’t solve it.

Comment: Have you tried something yet? Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: @Whatamidoing yup, sorry I should’ve write it. Yes, n∈N.

Comment: Is there by any chance a typo here? Did you mean the term in the exponent to be $-\frac{1}{4}{(x - \xi)}^2$?

Comment: No. I don’t think there’s any type. But sorry I didn’t explain why I thought about it. I will write more

Comment: Well, there must be some problem somewhere, because the integral always diverges as written.

Comment: The [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform) *should* have the form I suggested.

Comment: @JohnBarber oops! My bad! I found a type. I corrected it. Thank you, John.